# Find coordinates of $y$, given $x$ and equation of a line

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to work out the midpoint of a straight line, which I can do fine.

However, instead of being given $(x_1, y_1)(x_2, y_2)$ I've been given the two $x$ co-ordinates and the equation of the line.

For example, find the midpoint given the straight line equation $f(x) = 0.5x - 3$ and $x_1 = 1$, and $x_2 = 10$.

How do I work this out?

Thanks.

Comment: Should that be $0.5x+3$? You wrote "$=$"

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Edited it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ by plugging $X_1$ and $X_2$ into the given function.

Answer (score 0):

how about finding the midpoint for $x$ ($\frac12(x_1+x_2)$) then substitute that in the equation to find the corresponding value of $f(x))$? btw looks like you typoed a = for a -. happens to me all the time.